# Can the Wink Hub 2 "listen" for away status from the Nest Thermostat v3?

Tags: nest-thermostat, wink-hub

I know that I can control a Nest thermostat from a Wink Hub (and app) by "pushing" commands to the thermostat (e.g. "turn up the temperature"). However can the Wink hub be notified when the Nest thermostat detects that I'm away? I want to use the away status as a trigger for a Wink Robot (e.g. "When I'm away, turn off the lights.")

Comment: Both devices have several generations. Are you referring to specific versions of the Nest thermostat and the Wink Hub?

Comment: @Helmar I updated my original question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Yes, apparently that's possible.**

In [this blog](http://www.smarterhomeautomation.com/reviews/wink-hub-review-nest-google-echo/wink-hub-review-nest-google-echo-7/) some possibilities of connecting Nest with Wink robots are described.

> The first Robot, I named “Someone’s Home’. I simply chose the robot to activate when Nest Away, detects someone is home.  I set the time period to anytime. Then as a result, I set the robot to alert me via email.

> My second Robot was not as diabolical.  .  When Nest detects we are away.  Wink will wait 10 minutes, then lock the door!

Thus, the Wink Hub can react to that away state of Nest.